# creating a for-loop that prints # signs instead of number values

Tags: javascript, for-loop

im trying to write a code that outputs lines of '#' signs that increase by one for each value until the input number is reached.

for example, when triangles(3) is called my desired output is:

```
'#'
'##'
'###'
```

ive learned how to create this sequence with number values instead of the '#' signs but not sure how to achieve this output displayed above.  thanks!

```
function triangles(num) {
  let number = '';

  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    console.log(number += i);
  }
}

triangles(5)
```

this outputs:

```
'1'
'12'
'123'
'1234'
'12345'
```

Comment: Output `i` value instead of `#`

Comment: console.log(number += '#')

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.prototype.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) to repeat the pound (`#`) character as specified by the current value of `i`, without needing to declare a new variable to store it:

```js
function triangles(num) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    console.log('#'.repeat(i));
  }
}

triangles(5);
```

Comment: brilliant. thanks a ton! this is exactly what i was trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

```js
function triangles(num) {
  let symbol = "#";

  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    console.log(Array(i).fill(symbol).join(""));
  }
}

triangles(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function triangles(num) {
  const c = "#";
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    console.log(c.repeat(i));
  }
}

triangles(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `console.log` to print `number += i` specifically. If you want to print `'#'` multiple times, you can use @Terry's answer (which is shorter) **or** you can use another for loop in your code (this approach could be simpler for beginners).

```js
function triangles(num) {
  let number = '';

  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    number++;
    let poundkeys = '';
    // dont use i again, name it something else (like j or k)
    for (let j = 1; j <= number; j++) {
      // just like you do number += i, add a pound symbol to poundkeys
      poundkeys += '#';
    }
    // now, log poundkeys
    console.log(poundkeys);
  }
}

triangles(5);
```

Also, a quick tip. Generally, it is better not to log `number += i`. Instead of:

```
console.log(number += i);
```

It is encouraged and more readable if you separate them:

```
number += i;
console.log(number);
```